# Manual series names in highcharter

Tags: r, ggplot2, highcharts, r-highcharter

Looking to replicate the following ggplot logic in highcharter.

```
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Petal.Length, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"), labels = c("My custom species name", "Another species name", "Species XYZ"))
```

This is the closest I can do

```
highchart() |>
  hc_add_series(data = iris, type = "scatter", hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, group = Species)) |>
  hc_colors(colors = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

The problem is that I need to manually override the group names without altering the underlying data. I am aware that each group can be added separately using `hc_add_series()`, but this is not an elegant solution, especially when the number of groups is large. Wondering if there's a code logic that is similar to what is available in ggplot.

Comment: Could you please explain again more precisely what functionality you are looking for?

Comment: @madepiet found the solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution that was simple, but not intuitive. Apparently, the `name` argument in `hc_add_series()` can take a vector of names. It would have perhaps been more intuitive if this argument was named `names` instead.

```
highchart() |>
  hc_add_series(data = iris, type = "scatter", hcaes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Petal.Length, group = Species),
                name = c("My custom species name", "Another species name", "Species XYZ")) |>
  hc_colors(colors = c("red", "green", "blue"))
```